# How to get mysql data from two rows and show them in single row by joining comma separated values?

Tags: mysql

Here I am retrieving  user id in Mysql  from two rows based onid_no so it will retrieve two separate rows but after that I Want that result should come in single row with comma separated.

query to get records:

```
SELECT uid FROM `users` WHERE id_no='f5e3fe73a8';
```

output:

[image]

but expected output 
uid=2,1
so how to do this using mysql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `group_concat`

```
SELECT group_concat(uid) FROM `users` WHERE id_no='f5e3fe73a8' Group by id_no
```

For more informations see [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: thanks got result as expected so one more doubt iwnat to know can i echo in php directly if yes then how to echo please suggest me this because in mysql getting column name like  'group_concat(uid)' .

Comment: @MSp add an alias `SELECT group_concat(uid) as uid FROM ...`